# Injecting a rule into a spock specification

Tags: spring, rule, spock

I'm trying to inject a rule which is configured in a spring context into a spock specification.

```java
@ContextConfiguration(locations=["spring.xml"])
class TestSpec extends Specification {
    @Rule @Inject //@Autowired
    public ActivitiRule activitiRule;

    @Deployment
    def "Process test"() {
    when:
    //...
    then:
    //...
    }
}
```

The problem is that spock instantiates the rule by itself without respecting the `@Inject` or `@Autowired` annotation. In JUnit this works as expected. Is it possible to inject rules into spock?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting use case. The problem is that Spock's Rule extension invokes the rule before Spock's Spring extension injects it. It may be possible to fix this. If you don't mind, please submit an issue at http://issues.spockframework.org. For now, only injection of `MethodRule`s (as opposed to `TestRule`s) will work as expected.

Comment: thanks for the info, I created the issue https://code.google.com/p/spock/issues/detail?id=320 I helped myself with a workaround that I posted as answer.

Answer (score 1):

As long as this does not work out of the box (see [Issue](https://code.google.com/p/spock/issues/detail?id=320)), a possible workaround that I found is to use a Spring TestExecutionListener instead of a TestRule, this is of course only useful if you are writing the rule for yourself.

In the TestExecutionListener you have access to the ApplicationContext and can get any bean you need.